# Passing a space-separated System Property via a shell script doesn't work

Tags: java, bash

I have this bash file:

```
#/bin/bash

PROP="-Dprop=foo bar"

java $PROP -jar Foo.jar
```

So, what I want to do here is pass a space-separated list as a System Property. But this somehow does not work:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bar
```

So, it seems that Bash breaks `-Dprop=foo bar` up into `-Dprop=foo`, `bar`. I tried everything from double quoting to escaping the space character but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note that this is really a shell syntax question ... applied to a Java use-case.  These answers will work for *any* use-cases where you need to expand shell variables on a command line while passing embedded spaces from the shell variables to the command in its arguments.

You need to add the quotation marks around the shell script `$PROP` expansion:

```
PROP="-Dprop=foo bar"
java "$PROP" -jar Foo.jar
```

For multiple `-D` properties:

```
PROP="-Dprop1=foo bar"
PROP2="-Dprop2=bing bong"
java "$PROP" "$PROP2" -jar Foo.jar
```

Yes, the multiple `-D` properties case is cumbersome<sup>1</sup>.

Embedding quotes in the shell variable (as some people suggested) does not work<sup>2</sup>.

Finally, you can pass options to the Java command using [the `@file` mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/java.html#java-command-line-argument-files), and you could generate an @-file on the fly to inject shell parameters into it.  But the end result is (IMO) liable to be worse than the problem that you are trying to fix.

---

<sup>1 - If there is a better way to handle the multiple properties case ... that actually works for `sh`, `bash` or `ksh` ... please comment below.

2 - Try it and see!</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Try PROP=-Dprop="foo bar" Or you could do

```
PROP="-Dprop=\"foo bar\""
```

Comment: I don't think this will work.  I think it will give you literal double-quote characters in the property value.

Comment: @StephenC: nope. There is an expansion level during substition into the command line here: `java $PROP -jar Foo.jar`

Comment: I've tried it, and it didn't work.  See [BashFAQ #050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Use the answer provided by @Stephen C ... I ran through it locally on a bash environment at my disposal.  His method works.

Answer (score -1):

Set the property as follows if there are spaces in the property value with multiple values;

```
PROP="-Dprop=foobar"
PROP="$PROP -DpropTwo='hello world'"

java "$PROP" -jar Foo.jar
```