# Java System Parameter causing NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, unix

I have a class which takes in various system parameters and prints them out:

```
public class Test_Class {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String fooA = System.getProperty("fooA");
        String fooB = System.getProperty("fooB");
        String fooC = System.getProperty("fooC");

        System.out.println("System Properties:\n"+fooA+"\n"+foob+"\n"+fooC+"\n");
    }
}
```

Then, using IntelliJ, pass in the VM Parameters as such:

```
-DfooA="StringA" -DfooB="StringB" -DfooC="String C"
```

Upon running my program I get the following output:

```
System Properties:
StringA
StringB
String C
```

Now, if I run the same program through a UNIX server by running the following command:

```
java -DfooA="StringA" -DfooB="StringB" -DfooC="String C" com.foo.fooUtil.Test_Class
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: C
```

I have tried a bunch of different ways to pass in `fooC`, such as `-DfooC=\"String C\"`, `-DfooC='String C'`, `-DfooC=\'String C\'`, basically any idea that came to mind.  I have done some research and have been unable to find any solid solution.

For reference, I found the following link online where another person seems to have the same issue but, unfortunately, none of the suggestions work.

http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/157761-issue-spaces-java-command-line-options.html

How can I pass in a System Parameter with spaces in UNIX? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `"String\ C"`?

Comment: How exactly do you run the program? If you type the command as you wrote it into a shell you wont get the error you quote.

Comment: Yeah, same error message is given.

Comment: Same as @Joni. Your command line works for me. You need to give some more details on how you run the program.

Comment: Did you check [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214392/passing-a-space-separated-system-property-via-a-shell-script-doesnt-work)

PROP="-DfooC=String C"
java "$PROP" -jar Foo.jar

Comment: Running it through PuTTy. I'm not sure if that changes anything. I'm not very good with UNIX but that is the command I run.

Comment: Still works for me - logged in to Linux server through Putty, then `java -DfooA="StringA" -DfooB="StringB" -DfooC="String C" Test_Class` prints all three properties.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743454/space-in-java-command-line-arguments) sounds similar to what you're experiencing, too.

Comment: under ubunutu your code is working with OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.5) (6b27-1.12.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) and with Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b20) also
is the server realy UNIX if yes which version. How you traied to use single quotation mark ?

Comment: I hava noticed that you are running it over putty that may be the problem. Please make sure that putty  character encoding is set to the same that uses the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach: Why not use a .properties file for storing the system properties instead of passing them through command line? You can access the properties using:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try {
  properties.load(new FileInputStream("path/filename"));
} catch (IOException e) {
  ...
}
```

And you may iterate as:

```
for(String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
  String value = properties.getProperty(key);
  System.out.println(key + " => " + value);
}
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: I ultimately followed a route similar to this, thanks for the suggestion.