# Passing a space-separated System Property via a shell

Tags: java, bash, shell, command-line-arguments, jvm-arguments

I'm having difficulties to startup a java program from a shell script (bash) where nested variables are used. Basically there are many system and -D java properties that need to be passed to a java program. I would like to organise them in a nicer way one below another as they are very difficult to read when in one line.

This is similar to
"[Passing a space-separated System Property via a shell script doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214392/passing-a-space-separated-system-property-via-a-shell-script-doesnt-work)" but not the same.

Here is a stripped down sample. Imagine a java program like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String s : args) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

When invoking it like this:

`java Main "First_Line" "Second line with spaces"`

It will give OK result like this response:

> ```
> First_Line
> Second line with spaces
> ```

However if script like this is used:

```
#!/bin/sh
PARAM01="FirstLine"
PARAM02="Second line with spaces"
PARAMS="$PARAM01 $PARAM02"
java Main $PARAMS
```

Then all spaces are eaten and second parameter is passed unquoted to java. Result looks like this:

> ```
> FirstLine
> Second
> line
> with
> spaces
> ```

Have tried to differently quote variables in a shell script, but so far without success. How to quote shell variables so that spaces are preserved and parameter is passed intact to java?

Comment: Use quotes: `java Main "$PARAMS"`

Comment: I think this is a known problem with shell scripts. It might be way tricky to fix. Could you pass a file instead of strings with spaces?

Comment: java Main "$PARAMS" does not work. It puts all output in one line.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta, only a problem with shell scripts that don't use modern extensions (such as arrays).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you put a shell variable on the command line *unquoted*, then it undergoes word splitting.  To prevent that word splitting, keep each parameter in double-quotes:

```
java Main "$PARAM01" "$PARAM02"
```

Or, if you want to get fancy, use an array:

```
PARAMS=("$PARAM01" "$PARAM02")
java Main "${PARAMS[@]}"
```

Comment: How can I do it with nested variables like PARAMS (which includes other variables)?

Comment: @ssasa with normal shell variables, it won't work. You can use bash arrays as shown in the updated answer.

Comment: This is great. I can even nest other arrays with PARAMS=("${PARAMS_A[@]}" "${PARAMS_B[@]}")

Answer (score 0):

Or you can't put params into separate file name for instance **params.in** and using Java8 is easy to work with

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Loading file (change with your way)
    final Path file = Paths.get("src/main/resources/params.in");

    // Printing lines or working with params
    Files.lines(file).forEach(line -> {System.out.println(line);});
}
```

Edit:
Small mistake, in case **params.in** is inside *src/main/resources* then it could be simplified.