# Passing a space separated value via shell is taking more argument then expected

Tags: java, shell, command-line, jvm-arguments

I'm having difficulties to startup a java program from a shell script (bash) where nested variables are used

```
export MAIN_CLASS="xxxxx"
MAIN_CLASS_ARGS=("$FirstArg" "$SEC_ARG" )
CMD="java some args here ${MAIN_CLASS} ${MAIN_CLASS_ARGS[@]}"
exec $CMD
```

And I am passing parameter as

```
export FirstArg = hello
export SEC_ARG ="hi Jam"
```

But In my main java class I have getting 3 parameter hello, hi ,Jam. But I am expecting it to be only two. What I am missing here can anyone help me.

I have checked some of the link as

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619615/passing-a-space-separated-system-property-via-a-shell)

But not able to fix it.

Comment: Instead of `CMD="java some args here ${MAIN_CLASS} ${MAIN_CLASS_ARGS[@]}"`, try `CMD="java some args here ${MAIN_CLASS} \"${MAIN_CLASS_ARGS[@]}\""`

Comment: @AshishSingh no this is not solving the issue

Comment: @Ashish those escaped quotes aren't syntactic, i.e. they don't protect the contents from word splitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `exec $CMD`, then word splitting is performed on the contents of `$CMD`. It doesn't matter how the variable was built up; at this point, it's just a string which is split by the shell.

Since you appear to be using a shell with support for arrays, then one option would be to do this instead:

```
CMD=( java some args here "${MAIN_CLASS}" "${MAIN_CLASS_ARGS[@]}" )
exec "${CMD[@]}"
```

That is, build up an array of all the arguments, then use a quoted array expansion, which prevents word splitting from taking place.

Comment: thanks this helps. i have executed it directly without wrapping in a variable cmd.