# Throws error when passing argument with space in JAVA_OPTS in Linux

Tags: linux, scala, performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

I am passing command line parameters to gatling script.

This works and executes my test in Windows operating system:

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-DuserCount=2 -DflowRepeatCount=3 -DdefinitionId=102168 -DtestServerUrl=https://someURL -DenvAuthenticationHeaderFromPostman="Basic UWRZm9aGwsxFsB1V7RXK0OlB5cmZvcm1hbmNldGVzdDE="
```

It works and takes input which is passed

```
**********************INPUT*************************************
User Count ====>>  2
Repeat Count ====>> 3
Definition ID ====>> 102168
Environment URL ====>> https://someURL
Authentication Header ====>> Basic UWRZm9aGwsxFsB1V7RXK0OlB5cmZvcm1hbmNldGVzdDE=
***********************************************************
```

I want to do this same thing on Linux System.
While if I use this command in Linux then it throws error or takes Null or Binary values as input
(Passing arguments with  ./gatling.sh)

```
JAVA_OPTS="-DuserCount=2 -DflowRepeatCount=3 -DdefinitionId=102168 -DtestServerUrl='https://someURL' -DenvAuthenticationHeaderFromPostman='Basic UWRZm9aGwsxFsB1V7RXK0OlB5cmZvcm1hbmNldGVzdDE='"  ./gatling.sh
```

Gives this error,

> GATLING_HOME is set to /opt/gatling-charts-highcharts-2.0.3 Error:
> Could not find or load main class
> UWRZm9aGwsxFsB1V7RXK0OlB5cmZvcm1hbmNldGVzdDE='

Here the problem is the space given in argument of `-DenvAuthenticationHeaderFromPostman='Basic UWRZm9aGwsxFsB1V7RXK0OlB5cmZvcm1hbm='`.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the $JAVA_OPTS variable is probably not surrounded by quotes. See this question: [Passing a space-separated System Property via a shell script doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214392/passing-a-space-separated-system-property-via-a-shell-script-doesnt-work)

[The gatling guys clearly forgot to do that](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/0184675c5460bf34447c68b1db235ee8f86c5feb/gatling-bundle/src/universal/bin/gatling.sh).

I would file a bug and/or just edit `gatling.sh`.

Ideally though you might just want to consider seeing if Gatling takes a properties file or [some other way to configure](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.2/general/configuration.html).

Comment: I have edited gatling.sh file with
java "$JAVA_OPTS" 
and executed this cmd: export JAVA_OPTS="-DuserCount=2 -DflowRepeatCount=3 -DdefinitionId=10221 -DtestServerUrl=https://URL -DenvAuthenticationHeaderFromPostman=\"Basic UGVyZm9ybWFuY2V0ZXZg0OlBasrewq1hbmNldGVzdDE=\""

Throws error: 
Unrecognized option: ... -DuserCount=2 -DflowRepeatCount=3 -DdefinitionId=10221 -DtestServerUrl=https://URL -DenvAuthenticationHeaderFromPostman="Basic UGVyZm9ybWFuY2V0ZXZg0OlBasrewq1hbmNldGVzdDE="
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit

Comment: Don't use the JAVA_OPTS variable. It just inherently difficult to make this work with bash shell escaping. Use the other forms of config: http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.2/general/configuration.html

Comment: can u please help me how can I write above parameters?

Comment: The link I posted to gatling configuration explain everything better than I could. Yes you are going to have to do a little bit of this own your own.